# Custom model validation don't work if model isn't valid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

There is a model

```
[CustomValidator]
public class Model
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string FieldA {get; set;}
    public string FieldB {get; set;}
}
```

If FieldA is null then CustomValidator don't work. The same behavior is for IValidatableObject.
Is there a solution to the problem?

Comment: Why not put Field A validation inside custom validator?

Comment: @NanYu I can. But it is inconvenient. I have many different models